# Build nested object arrays within recursive function

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, ecmascript-6

As per my original question geared specifically for React ([React recursive tree pass JSON path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207337/react-recursive-tree-pass-json-path)), I have realised the problem is pretty generic.

I have a recursive function that essentially loops through a treelike JSON structure, each time it outputs a branch I want to pass an object of the structures location in the tree like below.. Is there a simpler way to pass the structure? Is the data structure poor / should each chid have a unique ID attached?

My JSON object is below so you can see what I'm working with.

Any help much appreciated!

**Level 1 child**

{value: "Fruit"}

**Level 2 child**

{value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical'}] }

**Level 3 child**

{value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical', nested_values:[{ value: 'Pineapple' }]}] }

**Code - kind of works, but then I get all values within the same nested_values array**

```
 const createSelectionHierarchy = (data, isSub, level = 2, hierarchy = {}) => {
        let children = [];
        if (isSub) { level++; }
        let obj = {};
        obj.name = cat;

        const cat = hierarchy.value;    

        for (let i in data) {

            const subcat = data[i].value;

            if (typeof(data[i].nested_values) === 'object') { // Sub array found, build structure
                obj.values = subcat;
                obj.nested_values = [];

                hierarchy.nested_values.push(obj);

                children.push(
                    <FilterItem key={i} data={data[i]} hierarchy={hierarchy} level={level}>
                        {createSelectionHierarchy(data[i].nested_values, true, level, hierarchy)}
                    </FilterItem>
                );
            } else { // No sub array, bottom of current branch
                children.push(
                    <p className="filter-item level-last" key={i}>
                        {data[i].value}
                    </p>);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }
```

**JSON**

```
{
        "value": "Fruit",
        "occurrence_count": 5,
        "nested_values": [{
            "value": "Berries",
            "occurrence_count": 3,
            "nested_values": [{
                "value": "Strawberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Blackberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Raspberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Redcurrant",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Blackcurrant",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Gooseberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Cranberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Whitecurrant",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Loganberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Strawberry",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }]
        }, {
            "value": "Tropical",
            "occurrence_count": 2,
            "nested_values": [{
                "value": "Pineapple",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Mango",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Guava",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Passion Fruit",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }, {
                "value": "Dragon Fruit",
                "occurrence_count": 1
            }]
        }]
}
```

**Desired output**

```
<FilterItem ...... hierarchy={{value: "Fruit"}}>
    <FilterItem ...... hierarchy={{value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical'}] }}>
        <FilterItem ...... hierarchy={{value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical', nested_values:[{ value: 'Pineapple' }]}] }}>
        </FilterItem>
    </FilterItem>
</FilterItem>
```

Comment: @r1verside - do you have an example?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - I updated my answer

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript (meaning ECMA Script) version of the code?

Comment: @Traktor53 - unfortunately not, but the above is pretty easy to decipher? It's just a function, the only wierd bit is i'm pushing JSX elements into an array instead of an object

Comment: @Zinc Please take a look at my answer to see if that's what you're after. I'll add an explanation if so.

Comment: @changed - yes please add explanation, looks interesting. How would I integrate this into the above?

Comment: @Zinc Updated, hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each branch (level of tree), this function will extract the value and then call itself on each of its children, if there are any, and store their return values in an array.

```
function convert(branch) {  
  const hierarchy = {
    value: branch.value
  };
  if (branch.nested_values !== undefined)
    hierarchy.nested_values = branch.nested_values.map(subranch => convert(subranch))
  return hierarchy;
}
```

```js
const input = {
  "value": "Fruit",
  "occurrence_count": 5,
  "nested_values": [{
    "value": "Berries",
    "occurrence_count": 3,
    "nested_values": [{
      "value": "Strawberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Blackberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Raspberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Redcurrant",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Blackcurrant",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Gooseberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Cranberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Whitecurrant",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Loganberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Strawberry",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "value": "Tropical",
    "occurrence_count": 2,
    "nested_values": [{
      "value": "Pineapple",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Mango",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Guava",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Passion Fruit",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }, {
      "value": "Dragon Fruit",
      "occurrence_count": 1
    }]
  }]
};

function convert(branch) {
  const hierarchy = {
    value: branch.value
  };
  if (branch.nested_values !== undefined)
    hierarchy.nested_values = branch.nested_values.map(subranch => convert(subranch))
  return hierarchy;
}

console.log(convert(input));
```

On a side note, what you supplied is not valid JSON (keys mustn't have quotes), it is a JavaScript object. To get an object from a JSON string, you have to call [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think you took my problem too literally, I'm just looking for the hierarchy object to have a new array structure pushed into it on each iteration. i.e. hierarchy={{value: "Fruit"}}, then hierarchy={{value: "Fruit", nested_values: [{ value: 'Tropical'}] }} etc

Comment: I guess I did. What you're after is even simpler - see the edit.

Comment: Cool, how would I work this into my recursive function above?